# uninstallation of a powershell cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, dll, powershell-cmdlet, pssnapin

I created my custom powershell cmdlet. It registers and installs fine, but when I try to uninstall it, I get an error. I use this command to uninstall it:

```
c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v4.0.30319\installutil /u 'path to .dll'
```

> Error: The uninstall is beginning. See the contents of the log file
>   for the 'path to .dll' assembly's progress. The file is located at
>   'path to log of installer'.InstallLog. Uninstalling assembly 'path to
>   .dll'. Affected parameters are:    logtoconsole =     assemblypath =
>   'path to .dll'    logfile = 'install log path'.InstallLog An exception
>   occurred during the uninstallation of the 'name of my installer'
>   installer. System.ArgumentException: Cannot delete a subkey tree
>   because the subkey does not exist. An exception occurred while
>   uninstalling. This exception will be ignored and the uninstall will
>   continue. However, the application might not be fully uninstalled
>   after the uninstall is complete.
>
> The uninstall has completed. An exception occurred while uninstalling.
>   This exception will be ignored and the uninstall will continue.
>   However, the application might not be fully uninstalled after the
>   uninstall is complete.

I looked at the registry. while I found few references to my cmdlet, removing them doesn't make a difference.

I currently uninstall by manually deleting the path that the installer of the cmdlet resides at. I'm not sure if this OK and wouldn't lead to problems in the future.

Do you have an idea on how fix this?

Comment: Which versions of PowerShell are you targeting?  If you drop v1, you can load your binary with Import-Module and you don't have to mess with snapin installation/uninstallation.

Comment: Also did you install your snapin under the 64bit reghive - using the framework64 version of installutil?  You can inspect the registry to see if your snapin is under the 64bit hive at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell` or under the 32bit hive at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\PowerShell`.  There will be a subkey called PowerShellSnapins under either the `1` or `3` key.